# What is the Android equivalent of java.time.Duration?

Tags: java, android, time

I need to use something like the class `java.time.Duration` to express time intervals from sub-microsecond to seconds. But Android Studio doesn't offer me this option.

I suppose I could use a `float` and express everything as seconds, but this seems less intuitive and meaningful.

These intervals aren't associated with any real-world timeline, they're just, well, intervals.

Comment: Maybe `javax.xml.datatype.Duration`? Or just import JodaTime

Comment: The `java.time` libraries only come into effect in Java 8 anyway, and the last I checked, Android can only use up to Java 7.  You may be able to get this effect with a third-party library like Joda Time.

Comment: @Makoto Might want to update your knowledge :) https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: @cricket_007:  Okay, so a *subset*.  But not the subset that the OP cares about, nor the subset that I was curious about.

Comment: @cricket_007 & Makoto – The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), and advises migration to [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), further adapted to Android in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). This back-port includes `Duration`. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42478897/642706).

Answer (score 6):

## Back-port

See the [back-port of much of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to Java 6 & 7, and its [adaptation for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See details below.

The back-port includes the [`org.threeten.bp.Duration`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Duration.html) class.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ;) You probably get tired of repeatedly answering these "simple" datetime questions with the same format.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that importing the `JodaTime` library and use the duration class from that could be helpful since you do not have access to the `java.time`library. 
From what I can gather the [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) and [ReadableDuration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableDuration.html) classes may be useful, but neither explicitly provide a `getSeconds()` method.

If you can use the above classes to store your time duration you could possibly create a static class to convert milliseconds into a seconds in a more intuitive way.

```
float durationInSeconds MyTime.milliToSeconds(myDuration.getMillis())
```

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted at [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) you should use desugaring if your gradle plugin is v4.0

Here you can find how to turn on desugaring:
[android library desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

It's pretty simple.